# Zip separately each folder using 7-zip

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I wrote this batch file to zip files each day separately.
However, I wanted to do it for folders. 
the problem is that for each day I have a different name for the folder. like:
20170530.daily
20170529.daily 
and on...

I've attached the batch I already wrote, can you look into this?

```
`@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" 
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
:: Your codes should start from the following line

@echo off
for %%A in ("E:\Logs\SmartLogger\*") do (if /I not "%%~xA" == ".zip" 7za.exe 
a -tzip -mx5 -y -- "%%~dpnA.zip" "%%~A" >nul && del /Q /F "%%~A")`
```